# Unable to persist XML to DB using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, jaxb

I have the below xml:

```
<business_partner_list>
    <business_partner>
        <business_partner_id>2004</business_partner_id>
        <business_partner_name>S. C. Johnson &amp; Sons Inc</business_partner_name>
        <last_changed_date>2016-02-02T04:04:04</last_changed_date>
        <department>
            <department_id>242</department_id>
            <department_name>TARGET.COM HARDLINES B</department_name>
        </department>
        <department>
            <department_id>98</department_id>
            <department_name>ADULT ATHLETIC &amp; MEN'S CASUAL</department_name>
        </department>
<business_partner/>
<business_partner>
        <business_partner_id>3821</business_partner_id>
        <business_partner_name>Johnson &amp; Johnson</business_partner_name>
        <last_changed_date>2016-02-02T04:04:04</last_changed_date>
        <department>
            <department_id>245</department_id>
            <department_name>OTC-PERSONAL CARE</department_name>
        </department>
        <department>
<business_partner/>
</business_partner_list>
```

I have parsed it using JAXB and I'm able to parse it. I'm using Hibernate and jpa to persist in DB.

So, it creates two Entity classes:

BusinessPartner.java and Department.java

These two entities should be persisted to DB using Hibernate and jpa.

> BusinessPartner.java

```
@Entity(name="businessPartnerType")
public class BusinessPartnerType {

    /*@Id 
    @GeneratedValue 
    protected long businessPartnerTypeId;*/
    @Id
    @XmlElement(name = "business_partner_id", required = true)
    protected BigInteger businessPartnerId;
    @XmlElement(name = "business_partner_name", required = true)
    protected String businessPartnerName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="businessPartnerType")/*(targetEntity=DepartmentType.class)*/
    protected List<DepartmentType> department;  
}
```

> Department.java

```
@Entity(name="departmentType")
public class DepartmentType {

    @Id
    @XmlElement(name = "department_id", required = true)
    protected BigInteger departmentId;
    @XmlElement(name = "department_name", required = true)
    protected String departmentName;
    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    protected BusinessPartnerType businessPartnerType;
}
```

Now what I want is when I persist BusinessPartner.java using hibernate and jpa, the mapping should happen automatically. But I'm getting the Exception:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find target.jaxb.beans.DepartmentType with id 242
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1142)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)
```

Which means I need to persist Department.java first and then BusinessPartner.java.

But is there any way I can persist BusinessPartner.java and Hibernate will do the rest by itself.

Comment: Please, add your persist code .

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the BusinessPartnerType to this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="businessPartnerType")
protected List<DepartmentType> department;
```

This should cause the DepartmentType objects to be automatically persisted.

Comment: Thank you so much Petter. It worked. By mistake I missed it.